# How to calculate average steps needed for state change in a state machine

Tags: probability

**Left:** 1/2 jump to Middle, 1/2 jump to self

**Middle:** 1/3 jump to Right, 1/3 jump to Left, 1/3 jump to self

How many steps on average is needed from Left to Right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $a$ be the mean number of steps required to get from Left to Right. Let $b$ be the mean number of steps required to get from Middle to Right.

We have
$$a=1+\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b,$$
and
$$b=1+\frac{1}{3}a+\frac{1}{3}b.$$